# add header to file created by "write.csv"

Tags: r, header

I am trying to automate some data exporting, and I would like to add a header to each file such as "please cite Bob and Jane 2008" ... or even a few lines of specific instructions depending on the context.

I have looked at the write.csv and write.table documentation, but do not see any such feature.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use `writeLines` to add a header and them `write.csv` with option `append=TRUE` to write your data.

Comment: `append` is ignored and automatically set to `F` for `write.csv`, use `write.table, sep = ','` instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are two possible approaches - the solution under **EDIT using connections** is more flexible and efficient.

---

## Using `write.table(...,append = T)`  and   `cat`

- Use `append=T` within a call to `write.table`, having `cat` the header there previously

wrapped in its own function....

```
write.table_with_header <- function(x, file, header, ...){
  cat(header, '\n',  file = file)
  write.table(x, file, append = T, ...)
}
```

Note that `append` is ignored in a `write.csv` call, so you simply need to call

`write.table_with_header(x,file,header,sep=',')`

and that will result in a csv file.

---

## EDIT

### using connections

(Thanks to @flodel whose suggestion is this)

```
my.write <- function(x, file, header, f = write.csv, ...){
# create and open the file connection
  datafile <- file(file, open = 'wt')
# close on exit
  on.exit(close(datafile))
# if a header is defined, write it to the file (@CarlWitthoft's suggestion)
  if(!missing(header)) writeLines(header,con=datafile)
# write the file using the defined function and required addition arguments  
  f(x, datafile,...)
}
```

Note that this version allows you to use `write.csv` or `write.table` or any function and uses a file connection which 
(as @flodel points out in the comments)
will only open and close the file once, and automatically appends. Therefore it is more efficient!

Comment: Consider using `file` and `close` to open and close a file connection. Otherwise you are opening and closing the file twice which is a bit inefficient. With an opened connection, you are always appending, so you won't need `append = TRUE`, and you can use `write.csv`.

Comment: To make this a completely flexible function, maybe add a line so it works even without a header. Something like `if(!missing(header)) writelines(headder,con=datafile)` .   Then you can name it "mywrite" :-) instead of "write.with.header.maybe"

Comment: 2nd function (my.write) worked for me as is.  1st function (write.table_with_header) needed "rownames = F"; consider moving the "edit" to top in case someone is lazy like me and doesn't scroll down